# ServiceStack: AppHost.OnRequestEndCallbacks handler gets called twice when an exception is thrown outside of a service

Tags: servicestack

I have a snippet in the OnEndRequestCallbacks block of the app host that records a row in an audit table for business purposes. The unexpected behavior is that when a request fails for some reason outside of a service (exception thrown), the endrequest event gets hit twice, and so 2 requests are audited instead of 1. This specific error is happening in the JwtAuthProvider when the token is expired. The exception funnels through as you would expect, but hits the end request callbacks handler twice. I added a snippet in the UncaughtExceptionHandlers block to write the error and end the request, but that doesn't seem to work, and 'two' requests are logged anyway. This was happening when I was getting exceptions in a Request Filter, but adding the snippet to write an error to the response and end the request worked in fixing the duplicates there. The same approach does not seem to work in the global handler in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should now be resolved from [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/81d1b5b370abb681670c5e8e6653464016ee46e8).

This change is available from v5.6.1+ that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'll update the libraries and check in later today.

Comment: Am not able to update the libraries right now since we're a bit behind and the jump involved some breaking changes, but i implemented your key fix in the OnRequestEndCallback handler and that seems to stitch up the issue for me, at least until the libraries get updated in the next week or so. Thanks again for your prompt response!